# Working with saveAssociated method in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.1, cakephp-model

I'm trying to work with `saveAssociated` method in `CakePHP` without great success, the method seems to work partially, in facts I have three model in the save process:
`Character`, which `$hasMany` > `Property` and `Label` so this is the `Character` model:

```
class Character extends AppModel {
    public $name = 'Character';
    public $belongsTo = 'User';
    public $hasMany = array (
        'Property' => array (
            'dependent' => true
        )
    );
    public $hasOne = array (
        'Label' => array (
            'dependent' => true
        )
    );
    public $validate = array (
        'name' => array (
            'required' => true,
            'rule' => array('between', 0, 100),
            'message' => 'This is the error message for "name" field'
        ),
        'description' => array (
            'allowEmpty' => true,
            'rule' => array('between', 0, 100),
            'message' => 'This is the error message for "description" field'
        )
    );
}
```

this is the data I get from the form:

```
array(
    'Character' => array(
        'name' => 'Character name',
        'description' => 'Character description',
        'image' => 'http://url.com/image.jpg'
    ),
    'Label' => array(
        'name' => 'Basic attributes',
        'value' => 'Value'
    ),
    'Property' => array(
        (int) 0 => array(
            'name' => 'Strenght',
            'value' => '15'
        )
    )
)
```

then in my `CharactersController` i do this to `saveAssociated` data:

```
class CharactersController extends AppController {

    public $uses = array ('Character', 'Property', 'Label');

    public function add () {
        if (!empty($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Character->saveAssociated($this->request->data);
        }
        debug ($this->request->data);
    }

}
```

The `Character` data is saved successfully but not `Label` and `Property`, where I'm wrong?

Comment: Are you getting any error messages during the save or just no action?

Comment: no errors are shown, I'll post how the array is sent to the controller.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this issue??

Answer (score 1):

Have you declared the other ends of the Model Association in the other two Models? Have a good look at [this page](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html). Might make life easier if you use a `$hasAndBelongsToMany` association.

Answer (score 0):

Try the saveAll method instead of saveAssociated.

Comment: For anyone stumbling across this, `saveAll` is for backwards compatibility. It essentially acts as an alias for `saveAssociated` and `saveMany` depending on the passed data. So wouldn't resolve the issue stated in the OP.